# redirecting pages does not work in IE

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have this code..

```
jQuery('#button_search').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var propertyUrl = getBaseURL()+'public/Property/view-property';
    var locationUrl = getBaseURL()+'public/Property/view-location';

    if($('#propl').is(':checked')) 
    { 

        var selectedLoc = jQuery('#select_location').val();

        if(selectedLoc == 'default'){
            alert('Please Select Location');
        }else{
            $().redirect(locationUrl, {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'});
        }

    }
    else if($('#propn').is(':checked')) 
    {

        var selectedProp = jQuery('#select_properties').val();

        if(selectedProp == 'default'){
            alert('Please Select Property');
        }else{
            $().redirect(propertyUrl, {'propertyId': selectedProp});
        }
    }
    else{
        alert('Select property or location');
    }

});
```

I used a customized button as the holder of the event..when I clicked that button after I select a certain item it supposed to redirect to the other page..it worked well in Firefox, chrome and opera yet it does not work in IE. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what IE is doing besides that it's redirecting, but if you've placed this button in a form, then my guess is that the form is submitting. You should `return false` at the end of your click handler to ensure that the default action of clicking the button (submitting the form) doesn't take place. Otherwise, some browsers may do the form submit, causing the redirect to no-longer occur.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..i'm using zend framework..that button  should supposed to bring the user to other page which corresponds to the users search request..im using jquery.redirect.js for my redirect function since i need to put a parameter to filter the results..it works in other browsers except IE..the button does not function in IE.